# JQuery on change event firing for the wrong element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `<select>` elements: `select.exerciseType` and `#moduleTopic`, each with their own handler wrapped around the `document`. I believe it's important to know that `select.exerciseType` is dinamic and there can be multiple of those.
Their events are:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("change", $("select.exerciseType"), function(e) {
        <!--Code not really important-->
    }
    $(document).on("change", $("#moduleTopic"), function(e) {
        <!--Code not really important-->
    }
}
```

My problem is, when I change the selected option in one of those selects, both those events are firing. Why is the selector in the on() function not working and how can I make it work?

Comment: The second parameter must be a string not a jQuery collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax for [**`jQuery` .on handler**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is **`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`** where second argument is `string`

In your case, as it is not `string`, it is omitted and the `event` is always triggered when it reaches the selected element!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", "select.exerciseType", function(e) {});
  $(document).on("change", "#moduleTopic", function(e) {});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this code instead:

```
$("#moduleTopic").change(function() {
 // code executes here
});
```

EDIT ---

You can use a classname and detect the `<select>` being changed by the use of `$(this)` inside your function.

Comment: Btw, *I believe it's important to know that select.exerciseType is dinamic and there can be multiple of those*, seen this?

Comment: TL;DR - It looks like the problem was the $(document) part, although my answer addresses **ONLY** this.. I guess I'm addressing the method of detecting change only.. I switched to ID rather than class, because it's not clear from original question how dynamically created elements might be generated so as to be unique..

Comment: Such handlers don't work with the dynamically added elements.

Comment: Yeah, `.exerciseType` is dynamic, so I can't put the handler on it.

Comment: @nicael even dynamically created, you can still get the value of `$(this)` when using the select: https://jsfiddle.net/tobyl/2uedr8pL/ - no?

Comment: I do not think so, the event doesn't fire because the handler was never attached to the element, for it did not exist when the handlers were attached.

Comment: The handler will simply target any existing DOM element with a class `exerciseType` (and the use of `$(this)` inside the function ensures your code acts upon the relevant `<select>`). Beyond that I guess I might just be unclear on what works and what doesn't..

Comment: TL;DR .. you have your solution, so either way I guess it doesn't matter.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need document.ready and you also just specify the selector, not retrieve it. i.e.

```
// class example
$(document).on("change", "select.exerciseType", function(e) {
    // Code not really important
});

// ID example
$(document).on("change", "#moduleTopic", function(e) {
    // Code not really important
});
```